# Ряды Тейлора c# - ошибка

Tags: c#

Почему при компиляции в следующем шаге после "-0.1" идет "-1,38...", а потом "0,999..."?

[image: При компиляции]

```
using System;

namespace OOP_Lab_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double x1, x2, step, eps, amount, func, x, value;
            int n;

            //Ввод данных пользователем

            Console.WriteLine("Eps= ");
            eps = 0.0001; // Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("x begin= ");
            x1 = -1; //Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("x end= ");
            x2 = 0.9; // Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Step= ");
            step = 0.1; // Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (x = x1; x <= x2; x += step)
            {
                n = 1;//
                value = eps + 1;
                value = 1;
                amount = 0;

                while (eps <= Math.Abs(value))
                {
                    value = -Math.Pow(x, n) / n;
                    amount += value;
                    n++;
                }


                func = Math.Log(1 - x); //Функция

                //вывод
                Console.WriteLine("\t x= " + x + "\t y= " + amount + "\t n= " + n + "\t auto= " + (Math.Round(func, 10)));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey(); Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что точных вычислений с плавающей точкой не бывает - ошибки округления постоянно накапливаются. Обратите внимание: там погрешность всего лишь 10 в степени -16, это очень мало!

Я бы посоветовал выводить x в формате F1, а y - в формате F4:

```
Console.WriteLine("\t x={0:F1}\ty={1:F4}\tn={2}\tauto={3:F4}", x, y, n, func);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если желаешь точных вычислений, то используй Wolfram Mathematica, а так полностью согласен с предыдущим ответом.
Просто инфа хранится в 2 системе счисления(с\с) и для не 0.1 в 10с\с не факт что будет будет простой, возможно периодической как 1/3 в 10с\с, вот здесь то точность и теряется. Возможно не только здесь.